# Javascript filter an array with another array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to implement a tag filter for a search and get an array of entries (variable: entries) like this with many entries:

```
"entries":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "details":"text",
         "tags":[
            {
               "id":9,
               "label":"Label9"
            },
            {
               "id":6,
               "label":"Label6"
            },
         ],
         "date":"Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM"
      }]
```

I want to filter this array with another array of tags (variable: tags) like this:

```
"tags":[
            {
               "id":6,
               "label":"Label6"
            }
```

At the end I need an array of those entries which contain all tags in the tags  array.             ]

I wrote this code but something is wrong. It compares the id of each tag.

```js
const entries = [{
  "id": 1,
  "details": "text",
  "tags": [{
      "id": 9,
      "label": "Label9"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "label": "Label6"
    },
  ],
  "date": "Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM"
}]



const tags = [{
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Label6"
}]


function containSearchTag(tags) {
  return entries.filter(function(el) {
    for (let i = 0; i < el.tags.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
        return el.tags[i].id === tags[j].id;
      }
    }
  });
}
console.log(containSearchTag(tags));
```

Comment: Because the filter is on the outer object, you don't really filter anything

Comment: I wrote you a snippet - please check and modify where needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array by checking the `tags` array with the set.

```js
var entries = [{ id: 1, details: "text", tags: [{ id: 9, label: "Label9" }, { id: 6, label: "Label6" }], date: "Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM" }],
    tags = [{ id: 6, label: "Label6" }],
    ids = new Set(tags.map(({ id }) => id)),
    result = entries.filter(({ tags }) => tags.some(({ id }) => ids.has(id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use of `Array.some` to make it easier; like :

```js
const entries = [{
  id: 1,
  details: 'text',
  tags: [{
      id: 9,
      label: 'Label9'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      label: 'Label6',
    },
  ],
  date: 'Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM',
}, {
  id: 1,
  details: 'text',
  tags: [{
      id: 9,
      label: 'Label9',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      label: 'Label12',
    },
  ],
  date: 'Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM',
}];


function filterByTag(tags) {
  return entries.filter(x => x.tags.some(y => tags.some(z => z.id === y.id)));
}

console.log(filterByTag([{
  id: 6,
  label: 'Label6',
}]).length);

console.log(filterByTag([{
  id: 9,
  label: 'Label6',
}]).length);

console.log(filterByTag([{
  id: 17,
  label: 'Label6',
}]).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let entries = [{"id":1,"details":"text","tags":[{"id":9,"label":"Label9"},{"id":6,"label":"Label6"},],"date":"Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM"}];
let tag = [{"id":6,"label":"Label6"}];
         
// Create an array of unique id's
 let ids = tag.map(({id}) => id);
 // filter only those entries which have all the tag ids specified in tag array
 let result = entries.filter(({tags}) => ids.every((id) => tags.some((tag) => tag.id === id)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This I hope it will help you

```js
var data = JSON.parse('{"entries":[{"id":1,"details":"text","tags":[{"id":9,"label":"Label9"},{"id":6,"label":"Label6"}],"date":"Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM"}]}');

let tag = JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"label":"Label6"}]');

data.entries.forEach((element)=>{
    element.tags.forEach((value)=>{
            tag.forEach((find)=>{
              if(find.id === value.id)
              {
                console.log("tag is avaliable ");
                console.log(value);
              }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An optimized solution can be to create a map of all the ids of tags present corresponding to each entry and than search for all the tag ids of the tag array. Search in map can be done in O(1) time. which can help in reducing the overall time complexity.

```js
var entries = [{"id":1,"details":"text","tags":[{"id":9,"label":"Label9"},{"id":6,"label":"Label6"}],"date":"Mar 8, 2018 2:45:30 PM"}];
 var tags =[{"id":6, "label":"Label6"}];

 var result = entries.filter((obj) => {
    var tagMap = obj.tags.reduce((a, o) =>{ a[o.id] = true; return a;}, {});
    var bool = true;
    tags.forEach((o) => {var x = tagMap[o.id] ? true : false; bool = bool && x;})
    return bool;
 });
 console.log(result);
```